# Some Sublime packages, such as MarkdownEditing, hide their commands in the command palette based on syntax. Is there a way to override this?

Tags: markdown, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

As an example, MarkdownEditing has some useful commands for navigating markdown files. However, it hides its commands from the palette unless the file is specifically set to a markdown syntax. At first, this seems logical.

However - for large markdown files it's sometimes better to view these without syntax highlighting (i.e. in Plain Text syntax) as the files open faster, but then one does not have access to the MarkdownEditing commands in the palette, which is a shame because large files are when some commands such as folding headers would really shine.

This is just an example but I believe solving it here might help others who have similar issues with other packages which hide their commands in the palette.

I discovered the package [Edit Command Palette](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Edit%20Command%20Palette), and this indeed allows one to add new commands to the palette, but if you add an existing command for a plugin which normally hides it as mentioned, it won't display the command.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I think perhaps the easiest way is to alter the package itself. Because MarkdownEditing doesn't install the source when installing from package control, you have to install it manually (which [is explained](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing#manual-installation) readme for this particular package) and then tweak the code yourself. If someone has some sort of override that wouldn't require tweaking the package itself that would be helpful and greatly reduce difficulty as some packages are quite large and it can take some time to find out which file does what.

In this case, if you look at the file mdeutils.py in the root project directory, just set `view_is_markdown` to return true always as that is the function which determines whether to display the commands / make them available for other syntaxes.

In short, in mdeutils.py, change this:

```py
def view_is_markdown(view):
    if len(view.sel()) > 0:
        return len(view.sel()) > 0 and bool(view.score_selector(view.sel()[0].a, "text.html.markdown"))
    else:
        return False
```

To this:

```py
def view_is_markdown(view):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The technical answer to your question is that it is indeed possible to stop commands from hiding themselves in the command palette. However for most commands, the reason they do this is not to de-clutter the command palette but more because they rely on the current state of things to be able to work.

This package may or may not be relying on something like that, so while you could make the commands appear that doesn't mean that they would work. In addition, changes like this require you to modify the plugin code itself because it is the actual commands that are in charge of whether or not they're active or visible.

All command classes support methods named `is_enabled()` and `is_visible()` that Sublime queries to see if that command should be enabled or displayed in any particular situation:

- When the command is a part of the menu, `is_enabled()` is invoked to see if the command should be enabled or disabled (greyed out) in the menu when it appears and `is_visible()` determines if it should appear at all.
- When the command is in the command palette, `is_enabled()` and `is_visible()` are invoked to see if the command should appear at all; disabled commands are hidden from view because they don't apply
- When the command is bound to a key, `is_enabled()` is called after you press the key and before the command is executed to see if it should be executed or not; `is_visible()` does nothing here.

So, if you were to locate the Python source for the commands that you're interested in, you could modify their `is_enabled()` methods to stop them from hiding themselves. An example of how to find that can be found in the video [Locating the source for commands](https://youtu.be/YbyZ4Vxk2fk).

Once you have access to the source, you can use [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit).

> **Disclaimer:** I am the author of both the video and the package

As noted above however, although this can make the commands appear when they would otherwise be hidden, that doesn't mean that they will actually work.

For example, a command might disable itself when there isn't selected text because it transforms the selection; in such a case, modifying the command to appear when the selection is empty doesn't mean that it will actually work when the time comes; it may do nothing, generate errors into the console, or possibly modify the file in unintended ways if the author used `is_enabled()` to ensure specific assumptions about the situation the command is executed in.

Other commands may rely on the syntax in use to be able to recognize parts of the file to know what to do; in such a case they may disable themselves in files of other types partly because they don't apply and partly because the information they need is not available.

I'm not familiar with the package that you're using here, so it may or may not be subject to this. For example if the heading folding you mention relies on the syntax to tell it what the headings are, then it won't work in plain text because that information isn't available. On the other hand if it analyses the buffer itself (say with regular expressions) to try and detect things, then it may still work as intended either way.